# How we can use FONT AWESOME by css

Tags: html, css, fonts

How can I use font-awesome in css? I searched and see that I just need to download and copy font-awesome directory into my porject then display the icon by using content in css.

---

Comment: Font Awesome CDN is the easiest way to get Font Awesome on your project [ http://fontawesome.io/get-started/ ]

Answer (score 0):

http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

Using CSS

```
Copy the entire font-awesome directory into your project.
In the <head> of your html, reference the location to your font-awesome.min.css.
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

```
Using CSS

Copy the entire font-awesome directory into your project.
In the <head> of your html, reference the location to your font-awesome.min.css.

<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Then in the code of the page you insert an icon like that:

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i>
```

For more examples, see [here](http://fontawesome.io/examples/). And here you will find the names of all [icons](http://fontawesome.io/icons/).